# GemFire 8.2 NPE in jGroups

Tags: gemfire

I observed the following Stack Trace on my GemFire 8.2 server after which it shut down.  What is the cause of this exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.AUTH.up(AUTH.java:134)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.GemFireTimeSync.up(GemFireTimeSync.java:282)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:259)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:274)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST.up(UNICAST.java:318)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.up(NAKACK.java:629)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:213)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:569)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.FD.up(FD.java:440)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:265)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.passUp(Protocol.java:768)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TP.handleIncomingMessage(TP.java:1198)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TP.handleIncomingPacket(TP.java:1110)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TP.receive(TP.java:1009)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.UDP$UcastReceiver.run(UDP.java:1388)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug that has been fixed in 8.2.1.  I believe it was in patch #2 but possibly the recent patch #3.

The AUTH class is looking for a membership view but in the wrong place and ends up with a null.